# VisualStudio - How to tell method is using for Relection or Serialization

Tags: c#, visual-studio, suppress-warnings

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and C#. Sometimes I have methods which are using by reflection or serialization and in warnings window I have information that method is not using. Is problem because while someone try refactoring code getting errors in runtime. Is any possibility to inform editor that method is using? Maybe some attribute for that (it will be the best solution)? Any ideas?

Comment: Much better would be to write a unit test that demonstrates how the methods are used

Comment: You're right but sometimes when I try fix something fast and I don't have time for writing tests for few classes but I would like to tell "This method is using". I can use comments too, I know. But maybe is possible mark better this method?

Comment: Dude can you please elaborate more , I can't make any sense from the question , a line of code is equivalent to 100 words :)

Comment: Put such code in a DLL instead of the main application...

Answer (score 0):

As an author of code, you cannot tell whether a method is being executed via Reflection. Because Reflection is late-bound, the compiler also cannot tell what method (if any) might be called by a Reflection Invoke.